# Creating database error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a database from my local computer through a stored procedure it is not allowing to create the database .

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Directory lookup for the file "D:\SHA_dat\SHA.dat" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
>   Msg 1802, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

And my code is here:

```
SELECT @cSQL = 'CREATE DATABASE '+@cDBName+' ON ( NAME = '''+@cDBName+'_data'''+', 
 FILENAME = ' + quotename(@cDbPath)+ ') LOG ON ( NAME = '''+@cDBName+'_Log'', 
FILENAME = ' + quotename(@cLogPath)+ ')'
select @cSQL
```

where @cDBName refers for the Datbase name to create and @cDBPath and @cLogPath refers to netork paths to create the .dat and .log files

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the value of the variables ? Even better: what's the actual SQL being run ?

Answer (score 3):

You write that @cDBPath and @cLogPath are network paths. This won't work. While the network path is available for you and you are submitting the `CREATE DATABASE`, the SQL Server service is processing the `CREATE DATABASE`. The service is running in it's own logon session with it's own user account and it does not have the same drives mapped as you have. So you cannot use a network drive as you do it.

BTW, the same applies when you want to recover from a backup. The backup needs to be available on a local drive so that the SQL Server service can access it.

Comment: Thank you for reply... It is executed successfully in Server. i mean production

Comment: Please elaborate. Where does it succeed, where does it fail? What are the values of the variables? Is D: a network drive? In which logon sessions is it mapped?

Comment: :When iam executing this sp from my local sql server it is giving above mentioned error, but while iam executing same sp in server it is executed successfully. cDbName='SHA' and cDBPath and cLogPath is '\\cServer\D:\Data\SHA.dat' and '\\cServer\D:\Data\SHA.log'

Comment: `\\cServer\D:\ ` is not a valid UNC path, do you mean `\\cServer\D\ `? Is cServer the database server? What are the accounts under which your local SQL server and the server's SQL server are running? It seems that the account your server's SQL server is running under can access \\cServer\D, but your local SQL server's account can not. Please add the relevant information to your question.